# What happened to the "menupath" token in the URL aliases for Drupal 7?

Tags: uri, tokens

Again, am I blind? If my "Widgets" page is under "Products," I want the auto-alias to be /products/widgets. I can't seem to find that in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 2):

http://drupal.org/node/807032

```
[node:menu-link:parent:url:alias]/[node:menu-link]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: `[node:menu-link:parent]/[node:title]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the Token module for Drupal 7, you will notice that the Pathauto module shows more tokens, some of which are for the menu link associated to the node, for example.

[image: screenshot]

When the code to handle tokens have been moved to Drupal 7 core code, not all the code has been moved; the theme function that shows the list of all the available tokens is still part of the Token module, and some of the tokens are only available after installing it.

Comment: I have token installed and saw those choices. AFAICT, those tokens are only for the current menu item (or immediate parent, or root). I want the full path down to the current item in my hierarchy.